# How to retrieve documents from subcollections in Firestore

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I am trying to retrieve all documents ("Spanish", ...) within sub-collection `group` for all groups and all `cards` for each group
The following returns all documents for group "Spanish"
But How to retrieve the documents if the name of the group is not known and when there are more than one

```js
db.collection('usersx').doc(this.user.email).collection('group').doc('Spanish').collection('card').get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data())
    })
  });
```

The desired outcome would be something like this:

```json
[
  {
    "id":"...@gmail.com",
    "group":[
      {
        "Spanish":{
          "cards":[
            {
              "front":"huis",
              "back":"house"
            },
            {
              "front":"auto",
              "back":"car"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "English":{
          "cards":[
            {
              "front":"test",
              "back":"test"
            },
            {
              "front":"bla",
              "back":"blabla"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Your output array of result is invalid, please check it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. It is now updated

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're going for (and your screenshot is difficult to read), but I suggest looking into collection group queries: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query

Comment: Thanks for the link. I already checked out that one, but could not find the answer there. The code in my question returns more or less the desired result, all cards for Spanish. But when I add a second group, e.g. "French" and create cards for French as well only the Spanish will be returned. But how can I retrieve the cards for all available groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch on the collectionGroup 'cards' - collection groups are *across* *all* structures, and there is no way to qualify the collection on a "parent".

What you *can* do is add the parent name as a *field* in your cards document, such as 'languageField:' (a safe operation because it will be static), then use that as part of a query:

```
// to fetch ALL cards
db.collectionGroup('card').get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data())
    })
  });

//to fetch SOME cards
db.collectionGroup('card').where(fieldRef:'languageField', opstr: '==', value: 'Spanish').get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data())
    })
  });
```

Incidentally, the doc.ref contains a field refPath, which is the fully qualified path FROM THE ROOT, which you can parse to find the specific language collection the card was part of.  I use a HIGHLY structured database, and use this approach all the time, including finding the parent(s) via the refPath.

Comment: Thanks LeadDreamer, refPath made it happen `let groupName = doc.ref.path.match(/(?<=group\/).*?(?=\/)/)` I hoped for a build in solution but this is a working alternative.

Comment: What happens if the collection contains random id? loop and get that value fine, but internal sub collection ?

Comment: Sub-collections are ENTIRELY created by you, the coder.  DESIGN your schema, and use it to your advantage.  The STRONG STRATEGY of NoSQL is to decide your *QUERIES* first, and design your SCHEMA to make them easy.